# Vs2010 show me this 0xc00000ba error after trying to run it

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It seems happened after I debugged a dump file.
How could I fix this? (Before I reinstall the IDE or even OS)

BTW, I am using Windows server 2008 R2

[image: Error message box]

Comment: OK, problem solved by myself, I found there are lot of folder named XXX.dll generated by unknown things at IDE's path. I deleted them all, and I got my VS2010 back.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some extra information to go with the solution you provided in your question's comment (remove all *.dll and *.pdb folders in your IDE directory).

I was playing with the Microsoft Symbol Server settings earlier today.  It must have dumped the symbol data into my IDE directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common7\IDE).  I removed all of the *.dll and *.pdb folders.  That did the trick.  They all had the same date modified, so I simply sorted by that column to find everything I needed to delete.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/333800/ide-wont-start-0xc00000ba-in-event-log-due-to-symbols-files-going-to-devenv-exe-dir

have a look, the solution worked out for the guy who asked it.
may help you as well.

Cheers,